# Why I can't install my grails plugin after reinstalling win7?

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I have a problem. After reinstalling win 7. I can't re-imported my Grails project. Im sure before reinstalling my win7, my project and my plugin run fluently.

[image: This is my grails project]

I have my own plugin "grails-melanin-2.0.0.zip" and place it in project.
I had to reintall STS 3.1.0, jdk, set java and grails environtment... But when I run this command : "install-plugin grails-melanin-2.0.0.zip" to install my own plugin, this error appear :

[image]

```
| Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      D:\grails-2.1.1/lib/commons-collections/commons-collections/ivy-3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:

      D:\grails-2.1.1/lib/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.1.jar

      D:\grails-2.1.1/lib/commons-collections/commons-collections/bundles/commons-collections-3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      D:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/commons-collections-3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:

      D:\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/commons-collections-3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      D:\grails-2.1.1\dist/commons-collections-3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:

      D:\grails-2.1.1\dist/commons-collections-3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Users\LAM\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/commons-collections-3.1.xml

      -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:

      C:\Users\LAM\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/commons-collections-3.1.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:

      D:\grails-2.1.1/plugins/commons-collections-3.1.jar

    ==== melanin plugin install resolver: tried

      -- artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1!commons-collections.jar:

      D:\CMC Soft\Collection System\CICDS/commons-collections-3.1.jar

      D:\CMC Soft\Collection System\CICDS/grails-commons-collections-3.1.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: commons-collections#commons-collections;3.1: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error Could not resolve all dependencies for plugin melanin
```

Please show me how to fix it ? Sorry my English is not good. Thank so much.

Edit : I place my Project at : D:\CMC Soft\Collection System\CICDS

My Grails at : D:\grails-2.1.1

My plugin at : D:\CMC Soft\Collection System\CICDS\grails-melanin-2.0.0.zip

Comment: do you have `mavenCentral()` repo enabled in your BuildConfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing everything from application.properties except the following lines:

```
app.grails.version=2.1.1
app.name=connectwebapp
plugins.tomcat=2.1.1
plugins.hibernate=2.1.1
```

Then, run

```
grails clean
```

Then, revert your application.properties

and run

```
grails run-app
```

Hope that helps!!!